# How to register an account on the testnet/mainnet?

Tags: accounts

What command do I have to run to request to register `my_acct_name` on the test net? Will it be the same for the main net?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's not a command to create an account on EOS chain out of a "thin-air". To create an account we always need a "parent" account which will create the new one.

So, if you want an account, what will happen is that some applications will have create an account for you upon signup.

From whitepaper:

> In a decentralized context, application developers will pay the nominal cost of account creation to sign up a new user. Traditional businesses already spend significant sums of money per customer they acquire in the form of advertising, free services, etc. The cost of funding a new blockchain account should be insignificant in comparison. Fortunately, there is no need to create accounts for users already signed up by another application.

https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#accounts

Comment: Great answer, but I'm still wondering say 1) who chooses the "applications" that get to register accounts? 2) what can I do on launch day to get an account and participate.

Comment: 1) You will choose an application that you want to sign in, not because an EOS Account, but because you want to use it, and then, you will receive an account if they stake your sign up I guess.
2) For now you can just buy any EOS Token and register it, so your address will be registered there in the launch day.

Answer (score 4):

## Before you start

You need to generate 2 sets of private and public keys, 1 for the `active` permission and 1 for the `owner` permission.

If you have access to `cleos`, you can do this with the following command:

```
cleos create key --to-console
```

Various wallets also offer the option to generate private and public keys.

The private key you should keep safe and never lose it. The public key will be necessary later.

### Creating an account on the Cryptolions Jungle Testnet

1. Go to the [Cryptolions Jungle Testnet Website](http://jungle.cryptolions.io/#home)
2. Click on create account
3. Type in the account name you would like and the public keys for the `active` and `owner` permissions.
4. The account will be created for you, and you can now use it on the Jungle Testnet

### Creating an account on the CryptoKylin Testnet

1. Go to http://faucet.cryptokylin.io/create_account?YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME_HERE (change YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME_HERE to the desired account name)
2. The webpage that appears will show you your public and private keys, unless the account creation failed because your account name had invalid characters, was not exactly 12 characters, or the account name already exists.

### Creating an account on the Main Net

How you do this depends on several things, as to create an account on the main net requires an already existing account on the main net.

Also, it costs about 0.7 EOS to create an account.

#### Ask a friend who already has an account

1. Its going to cost your friend, so make sure you pay them back!

#### What if I have no friends?

1. You can create an account through an exchange. You can do this by transferring EOS from an exchange to a specific EOS account that is trustworthy and specifying the account name you would like created and the public keys for the owner and active permissions.
2. See [this answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/how-will-someone-new-to-eos-create-an-eos-account-today/1225#1225) for various account creation smart contracts and tools.
3. Try and make some friends