# If all newly created accounts are servants, what permissions do the master accounts retain?

Tags: create

[No new accounts can be created on the EOS main chain](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-to-register-an-account-on-the-testnet-mainnet/11#11).  New EOS accounts can only be created from key pairs that were registered for the genesis.

This means these master accounts create what are known as [servant accounts](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-servants).

This leads to my questions:

- What rights do Master Accounts retain by default over servant?
- [When an account is created](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-create-account), are a new pair of owner/active keys able to be over written by the master without holding those new keys?

---

A potential way of creating new accounts could be an identity limited faucet funded by a WP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existing accounts may create new accounts, but that doesn't make the new accounts servants of the existing ones. By default, they're not.

There are two cleos commands which create accounts:

- [`cleos create account`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-create-account) only works when the system contract isn't loaded
- [`cleos system newaccount`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-newaccount) only works when the system contract is loaded. The mainchain is like this.

Both commands have arguments for the owner and active public keys. After creation, these are the only keys which control that account. Another command, [`cleos set account permission`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-set-account), can make one account a servant of another. You have to have the private keys associated with an account to use this command.