# Generated a EOS public private key pair offline. How do I link an account to it?

Tags: accounts, account-name, keys, public-key, private-key

I created a **EOS public private key pair** using eosio.js library and now I want to link this key with an account to make it usable so I can receive funds.

How can I do this? And where can I do this? What are my options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How will someone new to EOS create an EOS account today](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/how-will-someone-new-to-eos-create-an-eos-account-today)

Comment: Not duplicate as those referenced links do not let you use your own private key, but instead generates a new one for you. I want to create an account with my own private key I generated.

Comment: i only checked out two of them but https://namevault.co/ and https://eos-account-creator.com/ from there seem to let you choose your key

Comment: Seems like namevault can do this. But what is the difference from owner public key and active public key?

Comment: please see [this article](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/accounts-and-permissions#section-authorization-and-permissions) for a better explanation than i can fit in comments (section Authorization and Permissions)