# Account creation on jungle testnet node?

Tags: nodeos, accounts, wallet, testnet

I have setup a node with jungle testnet and it starts syncing the blocks. The chain id and server version are same as on jungle testnet. Now I have to wait for the completion of blocks to create an account and wallet. I was unable to create an new account.

Comment: Hey Hasnat, thanks for joining us on this Stack Exchange. If you click on the link in the above comment, you will find a detailed explanation of how to create accounts on the various testnets. I hope this is helpful, and if so, please upvote the answers that helped you the most so that other users can find them in the future.

Comment: if you don't want to read, just open http://monitor.jungletestnet.io/#faucet and create an account.

Comment: Why are you syncing a node with jungle test net. Just us the url of jungle test net. Test you code there and after testing sync with main net.

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: @HasnatAhmed Click here to see the answer to your question: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/3247/1232